# Is there a way to enable/disable IPv6 without restarting Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, dns, ipv6

**chrome://net-internals/dns#dns** has a button which allows us to enable IPv6 for Host resolver:

[image]

This is how it looks like after clicking <kbd>Enable IPv6</kbd>:

[image]

How do I revert to the previous state without restarting Chrome? Is there a <kbd>Disable IPv6</kbd> button?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/174715/is-there-a-way-to-disable-ipv6-in-googles-chrome

Comment: @MichaelHampton I believe it's a totally different thing.